# How to delete text after a marker

Tags: bash, sed, bash-scripting

I’ve got a piece html code And I try to extract the first paragraph.

html is like this :

```
<p>
    Hi. Lorem Ipsum<br />
    dolor si amet […]
</p>
<p>…</p>
<p>…</p>
```

I first thought using `sed 's/<\/p>*/<\/p>'` but it don’t seem to work : it do nothing

Any idea ?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552), use an HTML parser. For example, if you have well-formed XHTML, you can `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//p[1]' file.html`

Comment: @glennJackman I thought it was very “oversized” to this kind of need. And suppose I want to use another marker let’s says “·” there is no way ?

Comment: I'm sure you can use sed to find a solution for this particular input. However the solution will be very fragile: if even the newlines change on the input file (which won't affect the html), your sed command will be broken.

Comment: Why would it not work ? sed treat newlines in which particular way ? (It’s my first “true” shell script, and I’m still learning shell’s utilities)

Comment: sed is strictly line-oriented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work OK. It uses string manipulation, not regular expressions. It should also handle the case where the open and close P tags are on the same line.

```
awk '
  !in_p && idx = index($0,"<p>") {
    in_p = 1
    $0 = substr($0,idx+4)
  }
  in_p && idx = index($0, "</p>") {
    seen_close = 1
    $0 = substr($0,0,idx-1)
  }
  in_p {print}
  seen_close {exit}
' file.html
```

Won't work as expected if you have nested paragraphs like

```
<p>
    Hi. Lorem Ipsum<br />
    dolor si amet […]
    <p>
        …
    </p>
</p>
<p>2nd paragraph</p>
```

XML/HTML is just really hairy to parse manually: use an HTML parser.

Comment: Work perfectly (even when <p>…</p><p></p> are “sticked”). thanks!